# Could not find the application on the device - Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

On launching my Xamarin iOS app in debug mode to a physical device, I was getting:

`Could not find the application 'com.xxx.yyy' on the device 'zzzz'`

Answering my own question here, as the cause turned out to be non-obvious.

Comment: Would the downmarker like to give the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use two different Entitlements.plist files, one for debug and one for distribution; I was mistakenly using the distribution version instead of the debug one.

Comment: Glad you solved it. You could mark this answer, which might help others with same question.  Here is some info about [Entitlements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/entitlements?tabs=windows) and [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows).